# Save axes plot as '.fig' in a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a GUI in MATLAB with two axes with handles respectively:

```
handles.axis1
handles.axis2
```

I want to save the contents of one of the two axes (i.e. handles.axis2) in an external MATLAB Figure File Format (.fig).

I want a .fig file so export_fig is not the solution of my problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Almost just quoting Jan's answer from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86693):

```
fh = figure;
copyobj(handles.axis2, fh);
saveas(fh, 'figure_file','fig');
close(fh);
```

See also: [`savefig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html), [`hgsave`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsave.html)

Comment: Perhaps you mean `fh = gcf;`. Using `fh = figure;` will create an empty figure

Comment: No actually the whole idea is to create a new figure and save that to file.

Comment: @Pooya With only this script I would have problems with position. I mean, the new axis copied to the new figure wouldn't fit the new figure window.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by fitting, do you mean [`xlim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) / [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html)? Can you provide an image?